# Chart JS is not loading in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, chartjs

I am trying to display a bar chart using chartJS in LWC. On the page load the chart bar doesn't appear. If i do inspect element then it appear. Below is the code -

JS -

```
@wire( getOpportunities ) getOpps( { error, data } ) {
    if ( data )
    {
        this.aggResult = data;
        console.log( JSON.stringify( this.aggResult ) );
        var labelset = [];
        var dataset = [];
        for ( let key in this.aggResult )
        {
            if ( this.aggResult.hasOwnProperty( key ) )
            {
                this.labelset.push( this.aggResult[ key ].Name );
                this.dataset.push( this.aggResult[ key ].Amount );
            }
        };

    } else if ( error )
    {
        console.log( "Error: " + error );
    }
}

    renderedCallback() {
        if ( this.isChartJsInitialized )
        {
            return;
        }
        this.isChartJsInitialized = true;
        Promise.all( [
            loadScript( this, chartjs + "/js/chart.js" ),
            loadStyle( this, chartjs + "/css/style.css" )
        ] )
            .then( () => {
                this._buildChart( this.dataset, this.labelset );
            } )
            .catch( ( error ) => {
                console.log( "error " + error );
            } );
    }

    _buildChart( dataset, labelset ) {
        let canvas = this.template.querySelector( "canvas.chart" );
        let context = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
        this.chart = new window.Chart( context, {
            type: "bar",
            responsive: true,
            data: {
                labels: this.labelset,
                //[ "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange" ],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Opportunities',
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(22, 50, 92)",
                        data: this.dataset,
                        //[ 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3 ]
                        borderColor: "rgba(22, 50, 92)",
                        fill: true,
                        pointBackgroundColor: "#26B99A",
                        pointBorderWidth: 2,
                        pointHoverRadius: 5,
                        pointRadius: 2,
                        bezierCurve: true,
                        pointHitRadius: 10
                    }
                ]
            }
        } );
    }
```

HTML -

```
<template>
  <template if:true={labelset}>
    <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default custom-background">
      <canvas class="chart" width="950" height="250" lwc:dom="manual"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div if:false={isChartJsInitialized} class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1"> ChartJs Not loaded yet </div>
  </template>
</template>
```

On page load it looks like this

[image]

If i do inspect element , then the bar appears -

[image]

Is there anything i am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you try it using a different browser? Could be something related to the cache?

Comment: Just try calling the chart method from wire method when you receive the data not from the rendered callback , replace the rendered callback with some other name and call that from wire method when you set the labeldata and dataset . Refer my answer for your reference - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/286745/74929

Answer (score 0):

This link can help you
[Bar Chart In Lightning Web Component Using Chartjs](https://www.forcetrails.com/2020/04/bar-chart-in-lightning-web-component-lwc-bar-chartjs.html?showComment=1606905601894#c4873339466158592662)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.